# Keycloak: multiple email addresses for one realm?

Tags: keycloak, multi-tenant

Is having multiple email addresses configured per a single realm supported in Keycloak?

My use case is that I want to send out the registration and password-reset emails from at least 2 different email addresses, based on where the request is coming from.

I believe its not supported out of the box, because I did not find any documentation about it, but I'd be interested in custom solutions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak just supports one SMTP setting per realm.

If you want to have a different solution/behavior, you have to implement a custom email provider SPI and deploy it as a provider in Keycloak.